# forEach not returning parts of string separately

Tags: loops

I currently just tried this:

```
var languages = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'];
languages.forEach(function(language) {
    alert('I love ' + languages + '!');
});
```

although it is returning the alert 3 times, it is returning it saying "I love HTML,CSS,Javascript!" three times, instead of each language, one at a time. I can't figure out why that would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your callback function:

```
function(language) {
    alert('I love ' + languages + '!');
}
```

doesn't do anything with `language`. It should be:

```
function(language) {
    alert('I love ' + language + '!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was following along with a lesson and only looked back to the variable, instead of the function. Thank you!